# Draw 3D plot of two classes according to 3 variables with R

Tags: r, 3d, plot

I have an R data.frame:

```
> str(trainTotal)
'data.frame':   1000 obs. of  41 variables:
 $ V1   : num  0.299 -1.174 1.192 1.573 -0.613 ...
 $ V2   : num  -1.227 0.332 -0.414 -0.58 -0.644 ...
   etc.
 $ V40  : num  0.101 -1.818 2.987 1.883 0.408 ...
 $ Class: int  1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 ...
```

and I would like to draw a 3D scatter plot of Class "0" in blue and Class "1" in red according to V13, V5, and V24.

V13, V5, V24 are the top variables when sorted by scaled variance, so my intuition tells me the 3D visualization could be interesting. Not sure if that makes sense.

How can I plot this with R ?

---

Edit:

I have tried the following:

```
install.packages("Rcmdr")
library(Rcmdr)

scatter3d(x=trainTotal[[13]], y= trainTotal[[5]], z= trainTotal[[24]], point.col = as.numeric(as.factor(trainTotal[,41])), size = 10)
```

which gives me this plot:
[image]

I am not sure how to read this plot.

I would prefer to see only dots of two colors, for a start.

Answer (score 1):

Perspective issues mean that static 3d plots are mostly horrible and misleading.  If you really want a 3d scatterplot, it's best to draw one where you can view it from different angles.  The `rgl` package allows this.

EDIT: I've updated the plot to use colours, in this case picked using the `colorspace` package, though you can define them however you like.  Specifying attributes for points is described on the `?rgl.material` help page.

```
library(rgl)
library(colorspace)

n_points <- 50
n_groups <- 5
some_data <- data.frame(
  x     = seq(0, 1, length.out = n_points), 
  y     = runif(n_points), 
  z     = rnorm(n_points),
  group = gl(n_groups, n_points / n_groups)
)

colors <- rainbow_hcl(n_groups)
with(some_data, points3d(x, y, z, color = colors[group], size = 7))
axes3d()
```

Comment: Thank you. How do you get different classes in different colors in the 3D plot?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this? Using `scatterplot3d`.

```
    library(scatterplot3d)

    #random data
    DF <- data.frame(V13 = sample(1:100, 10, T), V5 = sample(1:100, 10, T), V24 = sample(1:100, 10, T), class = sample(0:1, 10, T))

    #plot
    scatterplot3d(x = DF$V13, y = DF$V5, z = DF$V24, color = c("blue", "red")[as.factor(DF$class)], pch = 19)
```

This gives:

[image: plot3d]

In `scatterplot3d` there is also an `angle` argument for different views.

Comment: Thank you. It works, but I prefer a 3d plot that can dynamically change angle with just a mouse drag, which doesn't seem to work with scatterplot3d.